# Use same JMS ClientID for multiple destinations/topics

Tags: jms, spring-jms, durable-subscription

I'm working on an new application that subscribes to two topics on a JBoss 4 and processes incoming messages. Actually I'm using two `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` with durable subscriptions for the connection.

When I use the same ClientID for the durable Subscription the Container fails with the error:

```
2021-07-02T10:28:05.487+0200 [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] ERROR org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TOPIC.providerDurableTopic' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: This client id 'ka03.9971.mueller.de' is already registered!
```

Are there any possibilities two use the same clientId for two different destinations. Is there maybe any other `ListenerContainer` that can handle multiple destinations with one container instance?

The reason we try to use the same clientId is because we try to replace an old application with it subscriptions. This old application connected to the topics within one JMS transaction and was able to use the same client id.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one possible solution is to use the SingleConnectionFactory and set the clientId on it. So only one Connection will be used for both Topics

Answer (score 0):

The JMS 1.1 specification explicitly prohibits multiple connections with the same Client ID. I see three potential solutions to your problem:

- Each message listener can use a connection with a unique Client ID.
- Both message listeners can use the same connection.
- Upgrade to a JMS 2 broker (e.g. [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/)). JMS 2 relaxed the requirements for durable subscriptions and Client ID is no longer strictly required.